# Why in Ruby 1.9 Continuations are evil?

Tags: ruby, continuations, fiber, fibers, continuation

I am relative new in Ruby world. And I don't know, what to think. In 'The Ruby Programming Language' I read I shouldn't use Continuations in new code and use Fibers instead. I found this presentation (from 2008) http://www.atdot.net/~ko1/pub/ContinuationFest-ruby.pdf which says that Continations are broken and creators of their Ruby's implementations are criminals.
On the other hand I read a few blogs where authors were showing their excitement about continuations and they didn't sad anyhing about continuations bugs.
So I don't know what to think. I know than it is better to use Fibers instead of Continuations, but what to do when Fibers aren't enough? Can I use Continuations or are they broken (presentation from 2008 says it)?
Why Matz kicked Continuations to stdlib? Why there are votes, he will kick it out from Ruby?

Comment: I don't know if they are evil or not.  The link is from the primary author of YARV, a Ruby VM, so I would consider it an "expert opinion".   You will probably get the best answer by asking about the best way to handle a specific programming problem in Ruby, where continuations might be one answer, instead of asking about the goodness of a whole feature.

Comment: This seems like [discussion for the mailing list](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/), but not a good question for Stack Overflow. Answers to this question seem to me to involve opinion instead of fact.